# Facebook dialog and the Back button

Tags: facebook, dialog, back-button, facebook-android-sdk

When using the facebook android sdk to open Dialogs it all works well.

However, if the user clicks the Back button then the dialog indeed closes but the *onCancel* method of the dialog listener (or any other method) is not called.

I searched about this matter and found this pull request from the fb android sdk on github: [Calls Cancel on DialogListener when Dialog is Cancelled](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/pull/189).

I took one part and modified it a bit to get this:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        mWebView.stopLoading();
        dismiss();
        mListener.onCancel();
        return true;
    }

    return true;
}
```

and I added it to the *FbDialog* class, and indeed this seems to do the trick.

What I'm wonderring is why isn't this a part of the sdk?
That pull request is more than a year old, and the last response is about 11 months old.
Why not adding it to the sdk source?

Since this solution is working it's not urgent, but I don't like to modify the source of the facebook sdk since it might be problematic later on (if/when they update).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

You should modify the **FbDialog** class.
Add this line to set the dialog not cancelable with the BACK key:

```
setCancelable(false);
```

Or add these lines to handle the BACK key click:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    mWebView.stopLoading();
    dismiss();
    mListener.onCancel();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I can't really test it since this code is not used any more..
Also, that still requires the modification of the fb source code.

Comment: @NitzanTomer Apparently facebook kind of abandoned that project, since there are currently 33 open pull requests, even duplicates of this same bug. I removed the cancelable on the fb code and it works great!

Answer (score 0):

You probably have SDK with a bug when the back button does not cause the cancel method to fire on DialogListener.

here check it out for a fix : https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/pull/189

After applying it you can implement it in your class like this:

---

```
//call for Fb login dialog
facebook.authorize(this, Constants.FACEBOOK_PERMISSIONS, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, (DialogListener) new LoginDialogListener());
```

---

```
class LoginDialogListener implements DialogListener{
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            saveCredentials(facebook);
            postToWall();
        }
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
            showToast("Authentication with Facebook failed!");
            finish();
        }
        public void onError(DialogError error) {
            showToast("Authentication with Facebook failed!");
            finish();
        }
        public void onCancel() {
            //back button pressed or dialog cancel pressed
            showToast("Authentication with Facebook cancelled!");
            finish();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Honestly I haven't checked this issue in a while, but why would you suggest that I use `Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH`? Using `SSO` is preferred for a better user experience.

Comment: If i remember correctly the main reason for this was that Non-SSO uses a nicer pop-over dialog to show the authentication panel while the SSO panel slides in from the right (and back out to the right after the user finishes). There doesn’t appear to be a way to change this UI, at least without hacking the SDK code directly.

Comment: Other reason was that one of the application requirement is not to use installed Facebook clients.